# Pattern matching in SML?

Tags: pattern-matching, sml

I'm just wondering what is XL variable here, it's not declared anywhere? This function returns NONE if a string is not in the list. Otherwise, returns the original string list but without the string matched.

```
fun same_string(s1 : string, s2 : string) =
    s1 = s2

fun all_except_option(s1: string, lst: string list) =
    case lst of
         [] => NONE
       | x::xl => if same_string(s1, x)    (* XL HERE ?? *)
                  then SOME xl
                  else case all_except_option(s1, xl) of
                            NONE => NONE
                          | SOME l => SOME (x::l)
```

Comment: That line *is* the declaration of `xl`, just like `x` (why are you confused about `xl` but not about `x`?).

Comment: Oh and x too. So we can declare that way without using val?

Comment: Yes, that's what pattern matching is all about: You can test which shape a data structure has and extract sub-parts by binding them to variables.

Comment: sorry what does x::xl mean please?

Comment: A list whose first element (head) is `x` and whose remaining elements (tail) are `xl` (another list). http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/stg/NOTES/node41.html#defn.of.list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As melpomene commented above, the `xl` on that line actually *is* the declaration of `xl`.

In Standard ML, variables are declared (bound) by using *patterns* that are then matched to *values*. This is true even when using `val`; for example, we can write:

```
val (x, y) = (1, "y")
```

to declare `x` (binding it to `1`) and `y` (binding it to `"y"`).

In `case` expressions and `fn` expressions, the pattern match also doubles as a conditional; for example, this:

```
val rec sum =
  fn nil => 0
   | h :: t => h + sum t
```

creates a function that checks if its argument is `nil`, in which case it does one thing, vs. if its argument has the form `value1 :: value2` (meaning a non-empty list), in which case it does a different thing (using those values). (Hypothetically, if the argument were to have *neither* of those forms, then the function would end up raising `Match`; but as it happens, *any* value of type `int list` will perforce have one of those two forms, so the function will never raise `Match`.)

Incidentally, note that that example *uses* the value identifiers `nil` and `::`, but does *not* declare them; whereas it *does* declare the value identifiers `h` and `t`. This inconsistency may seem strange; the reason for it is that `nil` and `::` are value *constructors*, meaning that they've been declared using `datatype` (`datatype 'a list = nil | :: of 'a * 'a list`), so they can be used in patterns. Something like this:

```
val nil = 3
```

is actually completely illegal, because `nil` refers to the constructor that's already been declared, and the types of `nil` and `3` are incompatible. By contrast, if an identifier is *not* already a value constructor, then appearance in a pattern constitutes a declaration (even if the identifier already *is* a value *variable*: the new declaration will simply hide the existing one). This can be a bit tricky for newcomers to the language, but with a little experience you'll find that it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a useful library function. Here are a few pointers on how to improve it:

1. Don't write your own `same_string` function that is exactly equivalent to the `=` operator. Simply use the `=` operator. Do this because of readability: Other SML programmers will identify the `=` operator but will wonder if `same_string` does something more. And why not let the function work for *''a* and not just *string*?
2. (Minor thing) Don't name your functions after the type they return. The type itself should be sufficient annotation. I.e. you won't accidentally use this function and not realize it's actually returning an *'a list **option***.
3. After a while, the following pattern:

   ```
   case f x of
        NONE => NONE
      | SOME y => SOME (g y)
   ```

   becomes a little tedious and you want to abstract the `SOME`/`NONE` part away, since the same thing always happens (either it's a `NONE` and nothing happens, or it's a `SOME y` and something happens to the `y`). Using the library function `Option.map` with the type *('a → 'b) → 'a option → 'b option*:

   ```
   Option.map (fn y => g y) (f x)
   ```

   It works just like when you map across a list. It might look like:

   ```
   fun all_except (_, []) = NONE
     | all_except (x1, x2::xs) =
       if x1 = x2
       then SOME xs
       else Option.map (fn ys => x2::ys) (all_except (x1, xs))
   ```

   And you might test it a little crudely like this:

   ```
   val test_all_except_1 = all_except (4, [1,2,3]) = NONE
   val test_all_except_2 = all_except (1, [1,2,3]) = SOME [2,3]
   val test_all_except_3 = all_except (2, [1,2,3]) = SOME [1,3]
   val test_all_except_4 = all_except (3, [1,2,3]) = SOME [1,2]
   val test_all_except_5 = all_except (1, [1,1,1]) = SOME [1,1]
   val test_all_except_6 = all_except (1, [1,2,1]) = SOME [2,1]
   ```
4. You may want to consider writing your functions in [curried form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying):

   ```
   fun curry f x y = f (x, y)

   fun all_except _ [] = NONE
     | all_except x1 (x2::xs) =
       if x1 = x2
       then SOME xs
       else Option.map (curry op:: x2) (all_except x1 xs)
   ```

   Here, `all_except` takes its two arguments separate from one another, rather than in a `(x1, x2::xs)` tuple/pair. And the value `(fn ys => x2::ys)` has been rewritten using the helper function `curry` in the following steps:

   ```
   (fn ys => x2::ys)           (* original *)
   (fn ys => op:: (x2, ys))    (* converting :: to a function *)
   (fn ys => curry op:: x2 ys) (* making it a curried function *)
   (curry op:: x2)             (* performing eta conversion *)
   ```

   The last step might seem cryptic. The function `curry op:: x2` is the one that takes a list and prepends `x2` to it, so it has type *'a list → 'a list*. If we temporarily called it `f`, we'd have `(fn ys => f ys)`, but that's just a [silly way](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) of writing `f`.